# relational symbol for "the same strings"

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

How to get the following relational symbol in the attached image? It's an altered equal-sign and is used by our tutor to denote "the same strings".

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\bumpeq` from the `amssymb` package.

Comment: What's the qay to negate this?

Comment: @myrco `\not\bumpeq`